# How to check if a hive column contains values similar to in operator

Tags: hive, hiveql

i am quite newbie in hive .I am having one requirement where i need to filter records having certain values similar in oracle database. I read something like array list but not sure how to implement that.Thanks for any help and appreciate for your time

I want to have a query similar below :

```
select * from table_name
where a in ('abc','bcd','def','efg')
```

Comment: What the problem with your current query?

Comment: Well ..i checked this query...It works ..I believe initially hive does not have a in operator ..but this works as well...Thanks for pointing this out